# Start new Activity with time limit

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity

I'm trying to start android call phone activity (Intent.ACTION_CALL) with time limit(Activity will work only in limited time e.g. only 10 seconds). Is there any way to do it or do I have to create my own call activity ?

//solution
My solution was to create service that have outgoing call receiver like in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-on-And

In receiver i have method

```
try {
        String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
        String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
        String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";

        Class<?> telephonyClass;
        Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
        Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
        Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
        Method telephonyEndCall;
        // Method getService;
        Object telephonyObject;
        Object serviceManagerObject;

        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
        telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
        serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
        serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);

        Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);

        Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod(
                "asInterface", IBinder.class);

        Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
        tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");

        serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
        IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
        Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);

        telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
        telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");

        telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with Activity with time limit?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Alarm Clock and use telephonyService.endCall() to end call